# Trying to Assert value using selenium webdriver but seems something wrong

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

What is wrong here :

```
  assert(Base.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainBG']/div[1]/form[1]/div/div[1]/div/span[2]/span/span").getText().contains?("Email address is required"),"Validation message for Email is firing")));
```

In Eclipse , it is showing bracket missing red line at **("Email address is required")**

Test Scenario :

There is login form , I am clicking on submit button without fill any data in email field and just want to verify it's validation alert message which is **Email address is required.**

Comment: Please post in detail what problems you are facing, what is the expected outcome and what have you tried already.

Comment: what is the problem , what is the error which you are getting, what is your input ? Some more details please

Comment: just updated question.

Comment: I'd suggest to use some temporary variables here instead of one long line to make things clearer for you.

Comment: @Sebastian - can you please share any example? or link where example is available?

Comment: See answer by francesco foresti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break it up like this to improve reading (note that I am making up return types)

```
Element element = Base.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainBG']/div[1]/form[1]/div/div[1]/div/span[2]/span/span"));
String elemText = element.getText();
assert elemText.contains("Email address is required") : "Validation message for Email is NOT firing";
```

Just out of curiosity, what is that question mark after `contains` ?

EDIT : since it seems that the assert is a native Java assertion, try it like this.

Comment: I was thinking that will work as conditional statement.:)

Comment: Now getting error for last line: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: well, that would work as part of a `? :` statement, but by itself it is not syntactically correct, hence the compilation error in Eclipse.

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer, see if it works this way

Comment: ok great , now no errors but should it print that successful message in console?

Comment: nope, the error message is printed only if the assertion fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89666/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-francesco-foresti).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Hamcrest assertions http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html:

```
assertThat(selenium.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainBG']/div[1]/form[1]/div/div[1]/div/span[2]/span/span").getText(), containsString("Email address is required" ,"Validation message for Email is firing"));
```

Probably you want to store the string to a variable first the print it (then delete this bit of code obviously) just to make sure you are asserting the correct data:

```
String emailData = selenium.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainBG']/div[1]/form[1]/div/div[1]/div/span[2]/span/span")).getText();
System.out.println("Data to be printed" +emailData);
```

And import:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```